# Using Lag() function to retrieve values across dates

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to use the LAG() and LEAD() functions in postgres to retrieve values from other rows/records in a table and I am running into some difficulty.  The functionality works as intended as long as the LAG or LEAD function is only looking at dates within the same month (i.e. June 2nd can look back to June 1st, but when I try to look back to May 31st, I retrieve a NULL value).

Here's what the table looks like

```
_date   count_daily_active_users    count_new_users day1_users  users_arriving_today_who_returned_tomrrow   day_retained_users
5/27/2013   1742    335 266 207 0.617910448
5/28/2013   1768    241 207 146 0.605809129
5/29/2013   1860    272 146 161 0.591911765
5/30/2013   2596    841 161 499 0.59334126 
5/31/2013   2837    703 499 NULL    NULL
6/1/2013    12881   10372   0   5446    0.525067489
6/2/2013    14340   6584    5446    2781    0.422387606
6/3/2013    12222   3690    2781    1494    0.404878049
6/4/2013    25861   17254   1494    8912    0.516517909
```

From that table you can see that on May 31st when I try to 'look ahead' to June 1st to retrieve the number of users who arrived for the first time on May 31st and then returned again on June 1st I get a NULL value.  This happens at every month boundary and it happens regardless of the number of days I try to 'look ahead'.  So if I look ahead two days, then I'd have NULLs for May 30th and May 31st.

Here's the SQL I wrote

```
SELECT
  timestamp_session::date AS _date
  , COUNT(DISTINCT dim_player_key) AS count_daily_active_users
  , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN days_since_birth = 0 THEN dim_player_key ELSE NULL END) AS count_new_users
  , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN days_since_birth != 0 THEN dim_player_key ELSE NULL END) AS count_returning_users
  , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN days_since_birth = 1 THEN dim_player_key ELSE NULL END) AS day1_users  -- note: the function is a LAG function instead of a LEAD function because of the sort order
  , (NULLIF(LAG(COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN days_since_birth = 0 THEN dim_player_key ELSE NULL END), 1) OVER (order by _date)::float, 0)) as AA
  , (NULLIF(LAG(COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN days_since_birth = 1 THEN dim_player_key ELSE NULL END), 1) OVER (order by _date)::float, 0)) as AB
  , (NULLIF(LAG(COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN days_since_birth = 0 THEN dim_player_key ELSE NULL END), 0) OVER (order by _date)::float, 0)) as BB
  , (NULLIF(LAG(COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN days_since_birth = 1 THEN dim_player_key ELSE NULL END), 0) OVER (order by _date)::float, 0)) as BA    

FROM ( SELECT    sessions_table.account_id AS dim_player_key,
    sessions_table.session_id AS dim_session_key,
    sessions_table.title_id AS dim_title_id,
    sessions_table.appid AS dim_app_id,
    sessions_table.loginip AS login_ip,
    essions_table.logindate AS timestamp_session,    
    birthdate_table.birthdate AS timestamp_birthdate,    
    EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (sessions_table.logindate - birthdate_table.birthdate)) AS count_age_in_seconds,
    (date_part('day', sessions_table.logindate)- date_part('day', birthdate_table.birthdate)) AS days_since_birth    

  FROM
    dataset.tablename1 AS sessions_table  
    JOIN ( 
      SELECT      
      account_id,
      MIN(logindate) AS birthdate
    FROM
      dataset.tablename1    
      GROUP BY
      account_id )
    -- call this sub-table the birthdate_table
    birthdate_table  ON
    sessions_table.account_id = birthdate_table.account_id
    -- call this table the outer_sessions_table
    ) AS outer_sessions_table
GROUP BY
  _date
ORDER BY
  _date ASC
```

I think that what I probably need to do is add an additional field in the inner select that reports the date as an integer value- something like that the EPOCH time for that date at midnight. But when I have tried that (adding a per day epoch time) it changes all of the values in the output table to 1.  And I don't understand why.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the days_since_birth calculation. I was using

```
    (date_part('day',
    sessions_table.logindate)- date_part('day',
    birthdate_table.birthdate)) AS days_since_birth
```

as though it was subtracting the absolute date to give me a difference between those dates in days, but it's just converting the date to a day of the month and subtracting that, so at the month roll over, it returns -27, -29, -30 (depending on the month).  I can fix this by wrapping it with an ABS function.